# {% include %} tag does not appear Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to make include **{% include %}** in Django. But I face some trouble

This is the base form.html file that I trying to inherit:

```
<form class = 'form' method = 'POST' action = "">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
<input type= "submit" value = "{{ btn_title }}"   />

</form>
```

and this is the inherited create.html:

```
**{% include "form.html" with form=form btn_title  = "Tweet"  %}
```

But Actually I have this error:-

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /tweets/2/update
Unknown argument for 'include' tag: 'input|btn_title'.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/tweets/2/update
Django Version: 3.0.6
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Unknown argument for 'include' tag: 'input|btn_title'.
Exception Location: C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py in do_include, line 311
Python Executable:  C:\Python\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path:    
['D:\\From Torrents\\Web , flask , django from torrent\\[FreeCourseSite.com] '
 'Udemy - Tweetme Build a Twitter-like app step by step with Django\\src',
 'C:\\Python\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Python\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python\\lib',
 'C:\\Python',
 'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 21 Dec 2020 16:35:25 +0000
```

Comment: The spacing is incorrect, it should be `{% include "form.html" with form=form btn_title="Tweet"  %}`

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of the [**`{% include … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include) is incorrect, it should be:

```
{% include "form.html" with form=form btn_title="Tweet" %}
```

Comment: Thank You ! 
This was my mistake , now it works

Answer (score 0):

You can check documentation of `{% include %}` [Django include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

```
{% include "form.html" with form=form btn_title="Tweet" %}
```